# Python Turning Bound Method Call Into Unbound

Tags: python, python-3.x

Writing a simple program that strips punctuation from a phone number and returns just the digits in a string:

`number = Phone("(223) 456-7890")`

`print(number.number)` ---> should return "2234567890"

The below code does this when '()' is added to the call, otherwise it gives a Bound Method error (understandable).

Issue is that the test suite wants it to return on `number.number` (no parens)

Checked the docs on this and various S.O. answers and have tried `self.number = ""` in the init method, then trying to load this variable with my results and return that, but that didn't seem to do anything. Any help would be appreciated thx

```
class Phone (object):

def __init__(self, phone_number):
    self.phone_number = phone_number
    #self.number = ""

def number(self):
    punctuation = ['\'', '+', '(', ')', '-', '.',',',' ']
    cpn = list(self.phone_number)
    [cpn.remove(item) for item in punctuation if item in cpn]
    self.number = ''.join(cpn)
    return self.number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a [property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work):

```
class Phone (object):

    def __init__(self, phone_number):
        self.phone_number = phone_number
        #self.number = ""

    def get_area_code(self, phone_number):
        punctuation = ['\'', '+', '(', ')', '-', ' ']
        #output = ''
        #for char in phone_number:
        #    if char not in punctuation:
        #        output += char

        return phone_number

    @property
    def number(self):
        punctuation = ['\'', '+', '(', ')', '-', '.',',',' ']
        cpn = [item for item in self.phone_number if item not in punctuation]
        return ''.join(cpn)

number = Phone("(223) 456-7890")
print(number.number) 
# 2234567890
```

I have modified the end of the method (there would be some additional improvements to do), using a list comprehension for its side effects as you did is not recommended, and `remove` as you used it would only remove the first instance of every punctuation character.